# Why Vuetify v-dialog value prop does not work when extending component?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

```
<!-- FormDialog.vue -->
<template>
  <v-dialog
    v-bind="$props"
    :value="tempValue"
    persistent
    @keydown.ctrl.enter="handleSave"
    @keydown.esc="handleCancel"
    @click:outside="handleCancel"
  >
    <v-card>...</v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
import { VDialog } from 'vuetify/lib'

export default {

  extends: VDialog,

  props: {

    // Direct binding to value prop does not work
    tempValue: undefined
  },

  methods: {
    ...
  }
}
</script>
```

I'm using a prop named `tempValue` binded to `value` prop, cause direct `value` usage does not work.

Using `value` (does not work)

```
<!-- ChildComponent.vue -->
<FormDialog
  :value="true"
  ...
></FormDialog>
```

Using `tempValue` (works)

```
<FormDialog
  :temp-value="true"
  ...
></FormDialog>
```

Do you know how can I use `value` directly?

Comment: Did you try using v-model instead of :dialog/:value to bind showDialog?

Comment: @ajitspyd in this particular case I don't want to use v-model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper way to extend a Vuetify component is to [wrap it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74206882/which-is-the-best-way-to-extend-a-vuetify-component).

```
<!-- FormDialog.vue -->
<template>
  <!-- No more $props but $attrs -->
  <v-dialog
    v-bind="$attrs"
    persistent
    @keydown.ctrl.enter="handleSave"
    @keydown.esc="handleCancel"
    @click:outside="handleCancel"
  >
    <v-card>...</v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
// Do not extend VDialog
export default {
  methods: {
    ...
  }
}
</script>
```